# Find special char and replace with space in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

stored procedure to find "%" OR "|" as an output; I want to replace it with a space.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [abc].[sp_name]
(
      @sysId INT=3
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @cStatusMessage VARCHAR(1000)
```

After receiving output in `@cStatusMessage` I am formatting text as below:

```
 select REPLACE(REPLACE(@cStatusMessage,'|','</br>'),'%','</br>')
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample records and the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you are looking for the following script:

**Input**:

```
'A%B|CDEFG%H||IJK||'
```

Script:

```
DECLARE @cStatusMessage VARCHAR(50) = 'A%B|CDEFG%H||IJK||'

select REPLACE(REPLACE(@cStatusMessage,'|',' '),'%',' ')
```

**Output**:

```
A B CDEFG H  IJK
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this query to do this replacement;

```
UPDATE [abc] 
SET [sp_name] = ' ' 
WHERE [sp_name] = '%' OR [sp_name] = '|'
```